# Error Getting Property

Tags: wix, wix2

So.. I've got this CA

`<CustomAction Id="InstallSetProp" Property="CustomActionData" Value="<some other data that's formatted exactly the same> /webconftmploc=&quot;[WEBCONFIGTMPLOC]&quot;" />`

However, when this CA is called, a message box is shown saying "Error Getting Property" which is bogus since the property is correctly set and accessible later on. (And does nothing except mess up my attempts to fully automate installation) I'm running the .msi through a bootstrapper that switches `/qr` to help with this.

The message box error is not shown when `/webconftmploc=&quot;[WEBCONFIGTMPLOC]&quot;` is removed, for the record `[WEBCONFIGTMPLOC]` is either an absolute file path or "Not Set" and I'm wondering if there's any special reason why this behaviour can occur.

However, I'm much more interested in any possible way to suppress or fix this action, of-course.

Comment: It turns out that the error message was coming from a different CA that was sharing the `<some other data that's formatted exactly the same>` and not recognising the extra property after it. Luckily it _seems_ you can pass variables over as Rob's post describes as well as still having access to the 'shared' variables in CustomActionData at the same time- not sure if it's best practice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `CustomAction` only sets a property. It is not possible for it to show an error message. If any of the properties were not defined they would just resolve to blank. Something else must be showing the error message.

However, it appears that you are trying to pass data to a deferred custom action due to your use of the specially named `CustomActionData`. That isn't quite the way to use `CustomActionData` though. Instead, the `Property` attribute should be set to the `Id` of the `CustomAction` that you want to pass data *too*. Say the custom action that uses that property value is something like:

```
<CustomAction Id='MyDeferredCustomAction' Execute='deferred' ... />
```

To pass it the string you are trying to send, you could write:

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallSetProp"
              Property="MyDeferredCustomAction"
              Value="<some other data that's formatted exactly the same> /webconftmploc=&quot;[WEBCONFIGTMPLOC]&quot;" />
```

Notice that the second custom action is setting a property with the same name as the deferred custom action: `MyDeferredCustomAction`. The `MyDeferredCustomAction` can access the value `<some other data that's formatted exactly the same> /webconftmploc="value_of_WEBCONFIGIMPLOC_goes_here"` via the magical `CustomActionData` property. You can read more about that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2w2fhwzz(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: I swear the WiX tag should just resolve to your name, Rob. :)

Comment: Naw, there are plenty of other people that do excellent work on the WiX toolset. I'm just happy to be one of them. :)